# Convert categorical data into various columns for plotting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to `python` and `pandas` but I've used `R` in the past for data analysis. I have a simple dataset:

```
df.head()

Sequence      Level    Count
       1       Easy        5
       1     Medium        7
       1       Hard        9
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
Sequence    Easy    Medium    Hard
       1       5         7       9
```

In `R`, I could simply do this by using the `reshape2` package. In `python` it seems like one of my options is to create dummy variables using `get_dummies` but that would still generate multiple rows for the same `Sequence` in my case. Is there an easy way of achieving my resultset?

I'm finally trying to plot it using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [1436]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='Sequence', columns='Level', values='Count')
Out[1436]: 
Level     Easy  Hard  Medium
Sequence                    
1            5     9       7
```

Then you could plot it:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Sequence', columns='Level', values='Count')
df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(df, index='Sequence', columns='Level', values='Count')` gives me the following error:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12265)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12216)()

KeyError: 'Sequence'

Comment: What pandas version are you using? Are you sure that in your dataframe you have column `Sequence`? Is you `Sequence` is an index for the dataframe?

Comment: If you have it as index you first need to do `reset_index`.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm connecting to `Redshift` which returns all column names in lower case by default. After I changed the column names to lower case i nthe `pivot_table` call, it started working as expected. Thanks a lot for your help.